# Project Euler #54 in Java: Comparing poker hands of two players

Tags: java, programming-challenge, playing-cards

I was bored the other day and decided to have a crack at [Project Euler Problem 54](https://projecteuler.net/problem=54) for some fun.  Given a file containing one thousand poker hands dealt to two players, the task is to count the number of hands won by Player 1.

This is the first project Euler problem i have completed and thought it would be good to get some feedback as i feel to help myself improve on my coding style and optimise the solution.

Card Class

```
public class Card {

private String card;

private String suit;

private cardValue value;

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public cardValue getValue() {
    return value;
}

public Card(String card) {
    this.card = card;
    this.value = convertValue(this.card.substring(0, 1));
    this.suit = this.card.substring(1, 2);
}

public cardValue convertValue(String v){

    switch(v){
    case "2":
        return cardValue.Two;
    case "3":
        return cardValue.Three;
    case "4":
        return cardValue.Four;
    case "5":
        return cardValue.Five;
    case "6":
        return cardValue.Six;
    case "7":
        return cardValue.Seven;
    case "8":
        return cardValue.Eight;
    case "9":
        return cardValue.Nine;
    case "T":
        return cardValue.T;
    case "J":
        return cardValue.J;
    case "Q":
        return cardValue.Q;
    case "K":
        return cardValue.K;
    case "A":
        return cardValue.A;
    default:
        return cardValue.fail;
    }

}

public String getCard() {
    return card;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.card;
}

}
```

Hand class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Hand {

private List<cardValue> broadwayList = Arrays.asList(cardValue.A,
        cardValue.T, cardValue.J, cardValue.K, cardValue.Q);
private List<cardValue> wheelList = Arrays.asList(cardValue.A,
        cardValue.Two, cardValue.Three, cardValue.Four, cardValue.Five);
private ArrayList<Card> handList = new ArrayList<Card>();

String hand;

public ArrayList<Card> getHand() {
    return handList;
}

public Hand(String hand) {
    this.hand = hand;
    createHand(hand);
}

public void createHand(String cards) {
    handList.removeAll(handList);
    for (String part : cards.split("\\s+")) {
        Card currentCard = new Card(part);
        handList.add(currentCard);
    }
}

public int getHighestCardValue(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    ArrayList<cardValue> cardValues = new ArrayList<cardValue>();
    for (Card c : hand) {
        cardValues.add(c.getValue());
    }
    cardValue maxCard = Collections.max(cardValues);
    return maxCard.value;
}

public cardValue getHigherSet(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = checkFrequency(hand);
    for (Map.Entry<cardValue, Integer> e : freqMap.entrySet()) {
        cardValue card = e.getKey();
        int freq = e.getValue();

        switch (freq) {
        case 2:
            return card;
        case 3:
            return card;
        case 4:
            return card;
        }
    }

    return cardValue.fail;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.hand.toString();
}

public Map<cardValue, Integer> checkFrequency(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<cardValue, Integer>();

    for (Card c : hand) {
        if (freqMap.containsKey(c.getValue())) {
            freqMap.put(c.getValue(), freqMap.get(c.getValue()) + 1);
        } else {
            freqMap.put(c.getValue(), 1);
        }
    }
    return freqMap;
}

public boolean checkFlush(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    String suit = hand.get(0).getSuit();
    int suitCount = 0;
    HashMap<cardValue, String> tempMap = new HashMap<cardValue, String>();

    for (Card c : hand) {
        tempMap.put(c.getValue(), c.getSuit());
    }
    for (String s : tempMap.values()) {
        if (s.equals(suit)) {
            suitCount++;
        }
    }
    if (suitCount == 5) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkPair(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = checkFrequency(hand);

    if (freqMap.containsValue(2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

public boolean checkTwoPair(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = checkFrequency(hand);

    if (Collections.frequency(freqMap.values(), 2) == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean checkThreeOfAKind(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = checkFrequency(hand);

    if (freqMap.containsValue(3)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean checkFourOfAKind(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = checkFrequency(hand);

    if (freqMap.containsValue(4)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean checkFullHouse(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    Map<cardValue, Integer> freqMap = checkFrequency(hand);

    Set<Integer> fullHouseCheck = new HashSet<Integer>(freqMap.values());
    System.out.println(freqMap.keySet());
    if (fullHouseCheck.contains(2) && fullHouseCheck.contains(3)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean checkStraight(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    ArrayList<cardValue> straightList = new ArrayList<cardValue>();
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (Card c : hand) {
        straightList.add(c.getValue());
    }
    Collections.sort(straightList);
    if (straightList.containsAll(wheelList)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (straightList.get(j + 1).showValue() == straightList.get(i)
                .showValue() + 1) {
            count++;
            j++;
        }

    }
    if (count == 4) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkStraightFlush(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    if (checkFlush(hand) == true && checkStraight(hand) == true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkRoyalFlush(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
    ArrayList<cardValue> valueList = new ArrayList<cardValue>();

    if (checkFlush(hand) == true) {
        for (Card c : hand) {
            valueList.add(c.getValue());
        }
        if (valueList.containsAll(broadwayList)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public handRankings evaluateHand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    if (checkRoyalFlush(hand)) {
        return handRankings.royalFlush;

    } else if (checkStraightFlush(hand)) {
        return handRankings.straightFlush;

    } else if (checkFourOfAKind(hand)) {
        return handRankings.fourOfAKind;

    } else if (checkFullHouse(hand)) {
        return handRankings.fullHouse;

    } else if (checkFlush(hand)) {
        return handRankings.Flush;

    } else if (checkStraight(hand)) {
        return handRankings.Straight;

    } else if (checkThreeOfAKind(hand)) {
        return handRankings.threeOfAKind;

    } else if (checkTwoPair(hand)) {
        return handRankings.twoPairs;

    } else if (checkPair(hand)) {
        return handRankings.onePair;
    } else {
        return handRankings.highCard;
    }

}

}
```

cardValue enum

```
public enum cardValue{
    Two(2),
    Three(3),
    Four(4),
    Five(5),
    Six(6),
    Seven(7),
    Eight(8),
    Nine(9),
    T(10),
    J(11),
    Q(12),
    K(13),
    A(14),
    fail(15);

    int value;
    cardValue(int v) {
      value = v;
    }
    int showValue(){
      return value;
    }
}
```

handRankings enum

```
public enum handRankings {

    highCard(1), // Highest value card.
    onePair(2), // Two cards of the same value.
    twoPairs(3), // Two different pairs.
    threeOfAKind(4), // Three cards of the same value.
    Straight(5), // All cards are consecutive values.
    Flush(6), // All cards of the same suit.
    fullHouse(7), // Three of a kind and a pair.
    fourOfAKind(8), // Four cards of the same value.
    straightFlush(9), // All cards are consecutive values of same suit.
    royalFlush(10); // Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace, in same suit.

    int value;

    handRankings(int v) {
      value = v;
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main m = new Main();
    m.parseHands();

}

public void parseHands() {
    int p1wins = 0;
    int p2wins = 0;

    try {
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("poker.txt"))) {

            Hand hand1 = new Hand(line.substring(0, 14));
            Hand hand2 = new Hand(line.substring(14, 29).trim());

            handRankings result1 = hand1.evaluateHand(hand1.getHand());
            handRankings result2 = hand2.evaluateHand(hand2.getHand());

            // checking a pair or higher set hand
            int pairValue1 = hand1.getHigherSet(hand1.getHand()).value;
            int pairValue2 = hand2.getHigherSet(hand2.getHand()).value;

            // finding the highest value card in the hand
            int highCardValue1 = hand1.getHighestCardValue(hand1.getHand());
            int highCardValue2 = hand2.getHighestCardValue(hand2.getHand());

            if (result1 == result2) {
                if (result1 == handRankings.onePair
                        || result1 == handRankings.twoPairs
                        || result1 == handRankings.threeOfAKind
                        || result1 == handRankings.fourOfAKind) {
                    if (pairValue1 > pairValue2) {
                        p1wins++;
                        System.out.println("player 1 wins\n" + hand1.toString() + " " + result1);
                    } else {
                        p2wins++;
                        System.out.println("player 2 wins\n"+ hand2.toString() + " " + result2);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (highCardValue1 > highCardValue2) {
                        p1wins++;
                        System.out.println("player 1 wins\n" + hand1.toString() + " " + result1);
                    }
                }

            } else {

                if (result1.value > result2.value) {
                    p1wins++;
                    System.out.println("player 1 wins\n" + hand1.toString() + " " + result1);
                } else {
                    p2wins++;
                    System.out.println("player 2 wins\n" + hand2.toString() + " " + result2);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + p1wins);
        System.out.println("\n" + p2wins);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Convention violations:

- You're not indenting your class bodies by one level. That makes me twitch and is against every single coding standard I know of.
- Also you're using a 2-space indent for each level. This is unusual (at the very least). The vast majority of java code is written with a 4-space indent.
- `cardValue` should be `CardValue`. Types in java are usually in `PascalCase` and not `camelCase`. The same applies to `handRankings` :)

#### Beginner standard "mistakes":

You have the following code (or very similar) multiple times:

> ```
> if (someCondition) {
>     return true;
> }
> return false;
> ```

note that it's irrelevant whether there's an explicit else-block there.
In both cases you can instead write:

```
return someCondition;
```

Note that this is also true when you `return false` in your if-block, as long as you `return !someCondition;` then.

---

Your code seems to often keep a reference to what the classes are based on. e.g in Hand you have the `String hand` field, which is set in the constructor and (from a quick scan) never used again. You don't need to keep a reference to original data, so long as you can reconstruct the input from what you make of it. Even then it's usually a "waste" of memory.

---

You're very reliant on the "standard" control structures. This isn't a bad thing per se, it just shows you're not terribly familiar with altenative ways to control program flow. Consider researching Streams and Lambda-Expressions

---

Your methods (almost) always take a specific implementation as parameter. Instead of `getHigherSet(ArrayList<Card> ...)` you should use the interface to allow extensible handling of different ways to store hands: `getHigherSet(List<Card> ...)`

#### Responsibilities:

It might be easier to have `CardValue` and `HandRanking` be responsible for evaluating Cards and Hands respectively. Since Java enums are actually classes with some compiler-constraints they can have methods defined on them. Consider moving `evaluateHand` into `HandRankings` and `convertValue` into `CardValue`.

This will make `Hand` and `Card` a little easier to read.

#### Stream opportunities:

The first thing that I would rewrite into a Stream is `checkFrequency`. What you'll need for that is `Collectors#groupingBy` and `Collectors#counting`. The implementation I'll leave to you :)

Other opportunities include most of the loops you have there.

#### Closing remarks:

Overall your code is written cleanly and easy to follow, which is awesome. In some places I can see you're new to Java, maybe even new-ish to programming overall.

Well done!

Comment: Hi there ! Thanks for taking the time to give detailed feedback, its much appreciated :) First off id like to say the indenting isnt like that in my version its just the way ive coppied it into the question (sorry !) I agreed with alot of things you mentioned such  as the conditions something i need to pay more attention too, im kicking myself now for not trying streams or lamdas as i was looking into them while working on this, but now i can go back and try and apply them. Looking back with your feedback i was being sloppy, as alot of the mistakes i should avoided. Thanks again bud.

Comment: Well indention might be personal preference as well as as setting of the IDE in use. What I miss most is a test case proving that this code actually does what it is supposed to do. Especially for such cases where the outcome is well known it might be instructive to try a [Test first](http://agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) approach.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use your `enum`

> ```
>     fail(15);
> ```

I'm not convinced that it's helpful to have a `fail` case.  In that situation, you would often be better off throwing an exception.  This should not be common.  In cases where you want to return a false value, try `null`.

> ```
>     int value;
>     cardValue(int v) {
>       value = v;
>     }
>     int showValue(){
>       return value;
>     }
> ```

More idiomatically and typically,

```
    private int value;
    private char code;

    private CardValue(int v, char code) {
        value = v;
        this.code = code;
        cardValues.put(code, this);
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public char getCode(){
        return code;
    }
```

By convention, a method that just returns a field value is call `getField`, where you replace `Field` with the capitalized field name.  This is called a getter.  I would expect something called `showField` to display the field somehow.

As [@Vogel612 suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139782/71574), I capitalized `CardValue` and switched to four column indentation.

I added two new fields and two new methods using them.  I did this because I wanted to change the constructor as well.

```
    TWO(2, '2'),
    THREE(3, '3'),
    FOUR(4, '4'),
    FIVE(5, '5'),
    SIX(6, '6'),
    SEVEN(7, '7'),
    EIGHT(8, '8'),
    NINE(9, '9'),
    TEN(10, 'T'),
    JACK(11, 'J'),
    QUEEN(12, 'Q'),
    KING(13, 'K'),
    ACE(14, 'A');
```

This shows how to use with the revised constructor.

The convention is for `enum` values to be ALL_CAPS.

#### Put logic where the knowledge is

Your `enum` knows what its codes are now, so use that.  Let it manage the code to `CardValue` mapping.

```
    private static final Map<Char, CardValue> cardValues = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (CardValue cv : values()) {
            cardValues.put(cv.code, cv);
        }
    }

    public static CardValue findByCode(char code) {
        return cardValues.get(code);
    }
```

Now rather than a long `switch`, your convert method could be

```
    public CardValue convertValue(String v) {
        return CardValue.findByCode(v.charAt(0));
    }
```

Further, if you change the `enum` later, this pattern will automatically update.  You won't have to roam around the code, looking for places where you assumed the original values.

#### `enum Suit`

You should consider having an `enum` for suit.  Then you could do the same kinds of things with it.

#### Mode

> ```
>     public cardValue getHigherSet(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
> ```

The most common element in a set is called a mode.  If there is only one, we call it a unique mode.

```
    public cardValue findMode() {
```

When I see a method called `getHigherSet`, I expect it to return the value of a field named `higherSet`.  So I would name this `findMode`.

#### Kickers and identical hands

You don't handle the case where the card values are identical.  For example, if both have the same pair.  In that case, it should go to the tiebreaker.  Either the other pair (if both have two pairs) or the highest card.  While the highest cards match, go down the list.  Apparently these are called [kickers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kicker_%28poker%29).

Also, a tie is possible if the two hands are completely identical in everything but suit.

You don't handle jokers wild either.  That's less of a problem, as you could just use rules excluding jokers.  Similarly, you could exclude Texas Hold 'Em, which has shared cards, allowing both players could have a three of a kind.  But you should handle base scoring, like hands with tied ranks.

You have multiple `System.out.println` calls.  Note that if you abstract the winning logic into a method, you could get this down to three.

```
    Integer winner = determineWinner(hand1, hand2);
    if (winner == null) {
        System.out.println(hand1.toString() + " tied " + hand2.toString() + "!");
    } else if (winner == 1) {
         p1Wins++;
         System.out.println("player 1 wins\n" + hand1.toString() + " " + result1);
    } else {
         p2Wins++;
         System.out.println("player 2 wins\n" + hand2.toString() + " " + result2);
    }
```

You might want to think about how you could reduce that down to just two with a `Player` class and an array.  Hint:

```
    Player winner = determineWinner(players);
    if (winner == null) {
        System.out.println("Tie!");
    } else {
        winner.incrementWins();
        System.out.println(winner.getDisplayName() + " wins\n" + winner.getHand() + " " + winner.getResult());
    }
```

#### Don't waste operations

> ```
>     Collections.sort(straightList);
>     if (straightList.containsAll(wheelList)) {
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

Consider

```
    if (straightList.containsAll(wheelList)) {
        return true;
    }

    Collections.sort(straightList);
```

Now you only sort if you needed.

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>         if (straightList.get(j + 1).showValue() == straightList.get(i)
>                 .showValue() + 1) {
>             count++;
>             j++;
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

First, `j` and `count` always have the same value.  So you could get rid of `j` and just use `count` instead.  Second, you don't even need to do that.

```
    int count = 0;
    int previousValue = straightList.remove(0).getValue();
    while (!straightList.isEmpty()) {
        int currentValue = straightList.remove(0).getValue();
        if (currentValue != previousValue + 1) {
            count = 0;
        }

        count++;
        previousValue = currentValue;
    }
```

This may look like more code, but realize that your previous code called `get` and `getValue` on everything at least twice.

This is also better because it doesn't hard code the value `4` in the loop.  This will loop over all the cards.

It's also better to declare variables as close to their first use as you can.  So declare `count` just before the loop starts, not above the other code.

You might get better performance if `straightList` is implemented as a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList`.  That would require testing.

> ```
>         if (freqMap.containsKey(c.getValue())) {
>             freqMap.put(c.getValue(), freqMap.get(c.getValue()) + 1);
>         } else {
>             freqMap.put(c.getValue(), 1);
>         }
> ```

You don't need `containsKey` here.  Consider

```
        Integer value = freqMap.get(c.getValue());
        if (value == null) {
            value = 0;
        }
        value++;
        freqMap.put(c.getValue(), value);
```

This saves you a `containsKey` call at the expense of a `get` call that will return quickly, as it fails its own `containsKey` check.

#### A shorter `switch`

> ```
>         switch (freq) {
>         case 2:
>             return card;
>         case 3:
>             return card;
>         case 4:
>             return card;
>         }
> ```

You do the same thing three times.  You can just write

```
        switch (freq) {
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return card;
        }
```

Be careful though, in the 2 case, you actually want to keep looping.  So you might want to do something like

```
        switch (freq) {
        case 2:
            if (mostFrequent == null || mostFrequent.getValue() < card.getValue()) {
                mostFrequent = card;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return card;
        }
```

And then later change

> ```
>     return cardValue.fail;
> ```

to

```
    return mostFrequent;
```

Note that if there are two pairs, this will return the card value of the larger one, which is usually what is wanted.

As previously discussed, under some rule variants, you might want to do something like that with three and four of a kind as well.  Consider using a `Heap`, `SortedMap`, or a `NavigableMap` instead of an unsorted `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed feedback ! much appreciated. Ill take these tips and improvements on board for sure. I didn't realise how much you could do with enums, this was my first time using them so its great to see how i can utilise them more in the future.